# Keeping Page Breaks the Same Reguardless of User

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I am having a problem with page breaks in the same document (on a server) moving when the same document is opened on another computer (actually the page breaks are not moving, but the number of pages within the print ranges changes).  The document needs to be opened and printed by multiple users.  I have seen posts from several users have this issue, but every just talks vaguely about adjusting the user settings.

What I really want is a way to save the document (or maybe some VBA code I could use) to keep the margins and print area the same no matter who is opening it.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VBA to explicitly set where the page breaks are.  Try using Macro Recorder to see how this is done.  Once you've made an attempt at some code, post this on StackOverflow.com instead.